# Unable to see Gitlab packages feature in permissions

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

I'm trying to use GitLab's NPM registry, so have set

```
gitlab_rails['packages_enabled'] = true
```

In gitlab.rb, but when I browse to **project settings | general | permissions**, *packages* is the only option missing; not sure how to troubleshoot further.

Using gitlab 12.10, installed in docker.

Answer (score 0):

So i believe i know why...

NPM registry is only available Gitlab Premium and above; since we are using GitLab CE, i assume that has only Gitlab *Core* features.